# Getting wrong data from JSON file

Tags: android, json, gson, android-webview

Im loading data (url) from a json file to a WebView (with gson). When i load the data from a different Activity through a static variable (WebView) i get the 12th url entry of my JSON file. When im loading the data to a inner WebView of my Activity i get the 1st url like it should be.

```
 OtherActivity.mWebView1.loadUrl(JsonData.getUrl()); --> here i get the 12th url
 mWebView2.loadUrl(JsonData.getUrl()); --> here i get the 1st url
```

They both use the same method to load the Data from the JSON file (gson):

```
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;


public String getUrl() {return url;}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

Here my LoadJsonFromAsset class:

```
 public class SwipeUtils {



public static List<AdInfo> loadProfiles(Context context){
    try{
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset(context, "adInfo.json"));
        List<AdInfo> adInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        adInfoList.indexOf("");
        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
            AdInfo adInfo = gson.fromJson(array.getString(i), AdInfo.class);
            adInfoList.add(adInfo);
            Log.d("test",adInfo.toString());
        }
        return adInfoList;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


private static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context, String jsonFileName) {
    String json = null;
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
        Log.d(TAG,"path "+jsonFileName);
        is = manager.open(jsonFileName);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

}

Comment: is this against the rules :/?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the method where i set the loadUrl(). It was in a loop an in the time where the loadUrl() worked it was already at the 12th entry.

Comment: So you fixed your problem?